# Parse html string to template in Go

Tags: go, go-templates

I have html stored in a table returning as a string, and I want to insert it into my html template. Currently it just renders as a string:

Eg. assume my `myHtmlString` var value is `<h3>Hello</h3>`

```
func (h *handler) buildEmailTemplate() model.myEmailModel {
    return model.myEmailModel {
        message: myHtmlString
    }
}

type myEmailModel {
    message: template.HTML '<h1>Hello</h1>'
}
```

I've tried changing this buildEmailTemplate function to parse to a template.HTML string unsuccessfully:

`message: template.HTML(myHtmlString)`

Comment: In what way was the attempted solution unsuccessful?  Did the value not render as expected or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to leave `<h1> </h1>` in html and pass "hello" or whatever as usual? By default passed argument can be empty string.